# Can someone explain what happened here?

Tags: login-screen

[image: ttps://i.stack.imgur.com/pkdld.jpg]

[image]

What I did before:

- Updated some apps and linux
- Installed some apps
- Used bleachbit then power off

Comment: It would probably help if you could recall exactly what you did - which apps you installed and updated etc. Also, did you actually manage to login, as seen in screenshot 2?

Comment: as for what apps I installed its PPSSPP, XDM and Mednaffe (emulator)

Comment: also I managed to login from the second screenshot

Comment: Also I discovered that all my desktop icons in the desktop are gone as well as my browser (brave)

Comment: One of your images looks like `xdm` - which fits given you actually said you installed `xdm`.  Why did you install it if you didn't want to use it?   *You weren't specific on what OS & release you are using, but your other image looks like focal so you've replaced the default `gdm3` with `xdm` by your install; you would have been asked which you wanted to use as default on install*

Comment: I installed xdm for downloading packs of roms since IDM isn't available for Linux but I didn't know that it will affect my system

Comment: so should I delete xdm and my system will be back to normal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of your images show a `xdm` greeter screen.

You didn't say what your release was, but the other image shows what looks like *focal* or 20.04 desktop.

Thus the install of `xdm` replaced the default `gdm3` with your replacement display manager.  You would have received a question that asked which DM (*display manager*) you wanted to use (given you'd installed a second DM), and it looks like you selected `xdm` - thus it's use.

You can use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xdm` to be re-asked the question you were on install; allowing you to return to `gdm3` as used DM.

FYI:  `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` would also ask the same question :)  as it'll list your installed choices & ask you to pick to use.

Comment: FYI:   This is what `xdm` is ; refer https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/xdm and you'll note it's a **X(11) Display manager** so I don't know what it has to do with any ROMs.

Comment: I mistakenly installed XDM that Changes your display for downloading files because I typed: "sudo apt install xdm" as X display manager